# Javascript disabled error during google plus sign in

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am using oauth2 for google plus sign in. I am using the rest version directly using `webview` in android.

During the sign in process, I can successfully enter the user id and password. After I press the login button, I get the following error on my screen:

[image]

And in the logcat, I receive the following log:

```
Redirecting to: https://accounts.google.com/o/noscript
```

Although using the same code, I am able to sign in using Facebook and Linkedin.

I also checked whether Javascript was disabled in Chrome or not and it was enabled.